# How to delete a character in bash read -d multiline input?

Tags: bash, readline

I'm writing a bash script that will use **readline** command to catch user's multiline input (list of packages), but I can't figure out how to delete (backslash) characters while inputing text (let's suppose I made a mistake). Below is the part of the code I'm implying.

```
read -d `echo -e "\e"` -p $'Give me a list:\n' PACKAGES
```

\e is the escape character to exit multiline input. Here what I got when I try to delete a character (I did tried all the methods I know: alt+backslash,ctrl+w;ctrl+u):

```
# read -d `echo -e "\e"` -p $'Give me a list:\n' vPACKAGES
Give me a list:
line one
line two
line 3^H^W^U^H^
```

As you can see ^H is how backslash was intrpreted, ^W =ctrl+w, so I'm unable to delete the any character only escape with *escape*. I did tried to play with read flags, -e letting me delete characters but *enter* becomes no longer a line breaker.

Thank you in advance for your advices and help.

Comment: Why bother doing it this way? Why not just loop until you get a blank or some other terminator? You only need to prompt once so it can look the same but it also means you can validate line-by-line if you want.

Comment: Can you, please, give a simple example I'm not sure I did get you right? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this this way at all. I would just prompt for values in a loop until you get an empty entry or some other delimiter.

Something like this (untested):

```
pkgs=()
printf 'Give me a list:\n'
while read -e pkg; [ -n "$pkg" ]; do
    # Validate package, etc., etc.
    pkgs+=("$pkg")
done
# Use `${pkgs[@]}` ...
```

You can use any other test instead of `[ -n "$pkg" ]` if you have some other terminating entry. (e.g. `[ "$pkg" = "." ]` to test for a `.`, etc.)

Or, as glenn jackman correctly adds, with newer (4.0+) versions of bash the new `readarray` builtin can be used here something like this:

```
printf 'Enter package names, one per line: hit Ctrl-D on a blank line to stop\n'
readarray -t pkgs
```

Comment: or, with a recent bash: `printf "Enter package names, one per line: hit Ctrl-D on a blank line to stop\n"; readarray -t pkgs`

Comment: Thank you Etan, the solution is a piece of a pie! You've made me happy! P.S. And good hint to read about bash arrays...