# Bash : read / readarray multiline input

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new on bash and I'm trying to write a bash script that will save user's multilines inputs (a text with newlines, somes lines of code, etc.). I need to allow newline (when you press "Enter"), multiline paste (when you paste few lines "Ctrl+V") and set a new key, instead of "Enter", to validate, send the input and continue to the next step of the script.

I tried with `read` but you can not do multiline.

```
echo "Enter content :" 
read content
```

I found an example with `readarray` here ([How to delete a character in bash read -d multiline input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389690/how-to-delete-a-character-in-bash-read-d-multiline-input)) that allow to press "Enter" for newline but each words separate by space are separate in the array. I would like to have only the lines separated.

```
echo "Enter package names, one per line: hit Ctrl-D on a blank line to stop"
readarray -t pkgs
```

Do you have any ideas ? Or there is maybe a completely different way to do it ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set IFS to newline so that only newlines will separate items in the array.

```
IFS=$'\n' readarray lines
```

The first line read will be `${lines[0]}`, the second `${lines[1]}`, etc.  `${#lines[@]}` tells you how many lines, and the last one will be `${lines[${#lines[@]}-1]}`.

To loop over the array, you should use `"${lines[@]}"`, not `${lines[*]}`; the latter will take you right back to looping over individual words.

Comment: Hello and thank you for this answer. I didn't know about IFS. For other people that are interested :
`echo "Enter package names, one per line: hit Ctrl-D on a blank line to stop"
IFS=$'\n'
readarray lines
for line in ${lines[*]}
    do
 echo "$line" >> result.txt
    done`

Comment: Don't try to put blocks of code in comments; it doesn't work well. :) Also see my edit.